# Can anyone please tell a advice to learn ROS properly like steps that allows me to do my projects?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello guys i try to learn ROS and its hard and every time i finish thing i would start from the beginning i cant even do a proper project

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399798/can-anyone-please-tell-a-advice-to-learn-ros-properly-like-steps-that-allows-me-to-do-my-projects?/) by [Midorya](https://answers.ros.org/users/91300/midorya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-04-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Midorya, I think you might have gone through these http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials but still may not be understanding some concepts and getting confidence in using ROS, I suggest watching video tutorials of ROS for better understanding. The Construct is one very good platform for learning ROS, here is the link - https://www.theconstructsim.com/. They have got video tutorials right from basic ROS concepts to advanced tutorials with video tutorials and even live sessions some times which can help you in better understanding ROS. You can get their videos on youtube also but they are limited so I suggest you make an account on their website.

Having an account will help you in enrolling for their free tutorials / courses and they also have their own online ROS development environment so even if you don't have ROS installed on your pc, you can still practise online. Check out their website to know more. Although there is limited content available for free, but I think that is sufficient for getting confidence in using ROS and doing ROS based projects. Hope this helps you, good luck learning !!

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I initially used `Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming - Third Edition` (I technically used the second edition back in my day, but I suggest using the third edition).

I quite liked that book. If memory serves, it started with some basic terms, then it went into URDF and you followed some steps to make a basic robot in Gazebo (the simulation program). Then you added sensors/controllers to that simulated robot, teaching you some basic stuff about URDF and simulations.

That's honestly where I stopped (in that book), because I had professors to help me with some more basic ROS stuff. However, it's a great way to be able to create and control (with keyboard teleop for instance) some simple robot that you've made in a simulation.

I personally like that way of starting with ROS, since it's a lot more "hands on" (even though everything is in simulation). You want to make some cool looking robot (in simulation) with an IMU, 3 lidars and a camera or 2, that book helps you do that. It's visual, which gives you some more satisfying results.

There's of course also the [emanual for Turtlebot3](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/). You don't actually need a Turtlebot3 for it, it has a chapter on simulations (just how to start it though, no actual knowledge) and you can run SLAM/navigation perfectly fine from the simulation.

Hopefully after that you'll have some understanding of ROS to ask specific questions (I get it though, ROS is hard to learn as a beginner). Since the more specific the question, the easier it will be for us to help.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Beware - I described my way of learning ROS 2 mostly, but I think it's still helpful for ROS 1.

Relevant question (ROS2): https://answers.ros.org/question/397619/can-someone-teach-me-how-to-love-ros2/

I learned a lot myself by reading the ROS2 documentation and the Nav2 stack documentation. For ROS1 I would assume the same thing - read and REALLY follow step-by-step documentation tutorials, try to modify the projects and packages too.

Daily reading of ROS Answers + helping others solve their problems is also the good way.

Important pages for me are:

- https://roboticsbackend.com/ (ROS 1 and 2),
- https://automaticaddison.com/ (ROS 1 and 2, a lot of projects)
- https://github.com/fkromer/awesome-ros2 (a list of resources for ROS2)

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-04-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1